# Parsing and filtering JSON to CSV using ogr2ogr flags

Tags: ogr2ogr

I want to export filtered data from JSON to a CSV by selecting a couple of fields and applying a where clause. I get empty output when using either the `-sql` or `-where` parameters with the `-select (field_list)` parameter.

Here are two different formulations of the command:

ex 1)

`ogr2ogr -f CSV "output.csv" "raw.json" -select "id","name","type" -where 'type="city"`

ex 2)

`ogr2ogr -f CSV "output.csv" "raw.json" -sql 'select id,name,type from raw where type="city"'`

The following query successfully exports desired fields but unfiltered.

`ogr2ogr -f CSV "output.csv" "raw.json" -select "d","name","type"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need single quotes around `city`, as it is a literal. Double-quotes indicate an identifier.

Try 
`ogr2ogr -f CSV "output.csv" "raw.json" -sql "select id,name,type from raw where type='city'"`

See the documentation for more information. 
https://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html#ogr_sql_quot

Comment: Check first with ogrinfo what is the real name of the layer that raw.json contains. It is not necessarily "raw". Read the Layer section from https://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html.